# N(T) and R(T) are T-invariant: application to proofs.

Tags: linear-algebra

Am I correct in assuming that since $N(T)$ and $R(T)$ are $T$-invariant,

$N(T^k)= N(T)$ and $R(T^k)=R(T)$,

$dim(N(T^k))= dim(N(T))$ and $dim(R(T^k))=dim(R(T))$

for all $k$?

If true, can someone give me the intuition behind this?

Comment: I can only assume that $N(T)$ is the null space and $R(T)$ is the row space. The notation is not standard. Both equations are false.

Comment: Invariant is a bit of a misnomer. We say a subspace $A$ is $T$-invariant if $T(A) \subseteq A$. Equality is not required.